# выход из selenium во всех потоках при ctrl + c

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, selenium

Всем привет, я пишу парсер для сайта с JS и поэтому использую selenium.
Так как мне нужно парсить несколько страниц сразу, я использую threading.
Вот часть моего кода:

```
def parser(data):
        options = Options()
        options.headless = True
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
        options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options,
                                   executable_path=r'/home/user/PycharmProjects/tgb/geckodriver')
        driver.get(data['link'])
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/button[1]'))).click()
        while True:
            try:
                price = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                    (By.XPATH,
                     '//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/main/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span'))).text[
                        2:-1]
                if price <= data['sum']:
                    time.sleep(3)
                    div = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                        (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/main/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]')))
                    link_order = div.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
                    send_mess(f'Требования: {data["sum"]}. Цена на сайте: {price}. \nlink: {link_order}')
                driver.refresh()
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print("quitting")
                l.release()
                break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open('setting.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    for i in data:
        t = threading.Thread(target=parser, args=(data[i],)).start()
```

После запуска все работает отлично, но когда мне нужно закрыть программу, я нажимаю ctrl + c, но куча браузеров остаются открыты в фоновом режиме.

Подскажите, как мне закрывать все браузера при закрытии основной программы

Comment: в вашем эксепшне driver.quit()

Comment: Вставил driver.quit() - все равно не закрываются окна(

Comment: А до `print("quitting")` код доходит?